# Access parser given an argument group

Tags: python, argparse

Given an argument parser with an argument group

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group_args = parser.add_argument_group(
    'Additional command-line arguments'
)
```

is it possible to access the parser object `parser` from the argument group `group_args`?

Comment: Yiu can explore the attributes `group_args` or the `argparse.py` source code.  But I don't think it stores its own 'container'.. A mutually exclusive group does have a `_container`.  And the group is referenced in the `parser._action_groups` list.  But nothing in the code requires the reverse reference.  Your own code could add `group_args.container=parser`

Comment: Adding an attribute to the `group_args` works for me. Forgot you could do this lol